# Groovy missingMethod

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to add a new method to my Groovy class dynamically, following the documentation. 
So here is my class which implements the methodMissing method:

```
class AlexTest {

    def methodMissing(String name, args){
        println "Method missing is called"

        def cachedMethod = { Object[] varArgs ->
            println "Hi! ${varArgs}"
        }

        AlexTest.metaClass."${name}" = cachedMethod
        return cachedMethod(args)
    }
}
```

and here is another groovy script which uses my AlexTest class:

```
def alexTest = new AlexTest()
alexTest.hi("Alex")
alexTest.hi("John")
```

I expect the "Method missing is called" to be called only once - as the method "hi" would have been 'introduced' inside the methodMissing. But, that methodMissing is being called twice, as if the "hi" method never gets introduced to the AlexTest class.

I have also tried to do it differently:

```
class AlexTest {

    AlexTest() {
        def mc = new ExpandoMetaClass(AlexTest, false, true)
        mc.initialize()
        this.metaClass = mc
    }

    def methodMissing(String name, args){
        println "Method missing is called"

        def cachedMethod = { Object[] varArgs ->
            println "Hi! ${varArgs}"
        }

        // note that this is calling metaClass inside the instance
        this.metaClass."${name}" = cachedMethod
        return cachedMethod(args)
    }
}
```

which sort of works, but only for that single instance. So if I create two instances of AlexTest, and call the 'hi' method, I will get two "Method missing is called" message.
Can anyone point me to the documentation which explains this behaviour?

Thanks in advance!

Regards,

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to the beginning of your first attempt:

```
ExpandoMetaClass.enableGlobally()
```

It works for me with V 2.0.1

If you prefer to enable on a class instance basis, [this post](http://mrhaki.blogspot.ca/2009/11/groovy-goodness-create-dynamic-methods.html) illustrates one way to do it:

```
class AlexTest {
    AlexTest() {
        def mc = new ExpandoMetaClass(AlexTest, false, true)
        mc.initialize()
        this.metaClass = mc        
    }

    def methodMissing(String name, args){
        println "Method missing is called"

        def cachedMethod = { Object[] varArgs ->
            println "Hi! ${varArgs}"
        }

        this.metaClass."${name}" = cachedMethod
        return cachedMethod(args)
    }
}

def alexTest = new AlexTest()
alexTest.hi("Alex")
alexTest.hi("John")
```

Comment: It is memory intensive though. :)

Comment: Michael Easter: Yep, I have that on my script towards the bottom. But as you mentioned, it is per instance. Not class wide. So everytime the 'hi' method is called on brand new instance, the 'methodMissing' is going to get called. Which is not what I want.

Comment: Hmmm... as dmahapatro pointed out (and from the javadoc), ExpandoMetaClass.enableGlobally() seems to be memory intensive. But I'm not sure how intensive it is. Also, where should I call this method, say in a web app ? During the context initialization?

Answer (score 1):

How about this in the script? This makes sure the methodMissing is implemented for the Class reference and is applied to all of the instances referring to it.

```
class AlexTest {

}

mc = AlexTest.metaClass
mc.methodMissing = {String name, args=[:] ->
        println "Method missing is called"
        def cachedMethod = { Object[] varArgs ->
            println "Hi! ${varArgs}"
        }
        mc."${name}" = cachedMethod
        cachedMethod(args)
}

def alexTest = new AlexTest()
alexTest.hi("Alex")
alexTest.hi("John")

def myTest = new AlexTest()
myTest.hi("Walter")
myTest.hi("Hank")

//Prints
Method missing is called
Hi! [Alex]
Hi! [John]
Hi! [Walter]
Hi! [Hank]
```

Although enabling ExpandoMetaClass globally works as well with a cost of little extra memory. :)

Comment: I have tried that, and that works. The reason I didnt like it is because I would like to keep 'methodMissing' within the AlexTest class itself. I'm not sure where is the appropriate place to put that methodMissing in an full application. I guess I'm coming from Java background, where everything has to be within a class.

Comment: If AlexTest is already expecting 'hi', it is better to implement `hi()` in `AlexTest`. I hope you got the point.

Comment: Yes, I agree. In this particular example, it is better to just implement hi() directly in AlexTest. But I'm talking about generating dynamic methods, like the finder methods in GORM. I'm curious about how GORM does it. Is it using ExpandoMetaClass.enableGlobally()?

Comment: Nope, they do not use that setting. All the possible dynamic methods are present as `finders` in `grails-datastore-gorm` module from `grails-data-mapping` and are added to domain class at runtime using reflection. Classes to look at is [AbstractGormApi](https://github.com/SpringSource/grails-data-mapping/blob/master/grails-datastore-gorm/src/main/groovy/org/grails/datastore/gorm/AbstractGormApi.groovy#L81). Also browse [finders](https://github.com/SpringSource/grails-data-mapping/tree/master/grails-datastore-gorm/src/main/groovy/org/grails/datastore/gorm/finders). @caffeine_inquisitor

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is caching the method closures in a `Map`.

```
class AlexTest {
    static Map methods = [:]

    def methodMissing(String name, args){
        if (!methods[name]) {
            println "Method is not cached"
            methods[name] = { Object[] varArgs ->
                println "Hi! ${varArgs}"
            }
        }
        return methods[name](args)
    }
}

def alexTest = new AlexTest()
alexTest.hi("Alex")
alexTest.hi("John")
```

Output

```
Method is not cached
Hi! [Alex]
Hi! [John]
```